# How SMTP (receiving emails) works?

Tags: smtp, network-protocols

I have a very hard time to understand how SMTP works.

I've read already:

- [Message Submission for Mail](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409)
- [Internet Mail Architecture](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5598)
- [Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)
- [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)

I know the SMTP server listens on PORT 25 and exchanges commands with the client.

Lets assume I own the domain **mydomain.com** and have there my own implemented SMTP server running.

Somebody want sent me (for example **bob@mydomain.com**) an email.

On My server I will see traffic like this:

```
Server Response: 220 mydomain.com SMTP
Client Sending : HELO domain.com
Server Response: 250 Hello domain.com
Client Sending : MAIL FROM: <me@domain.com>
Server Response: 250 Ok
Client Sending : RCPT TO: <bob@mydomain.com>
Server Response: 250 Ok
Client Sending : DATA
Server Response: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Client Sending : Subject: Example Message
Client Sending : From: me@domain.com
Client Sending : To: bob@mydomain.com
Client Sending :
Client Sending : Yo,
Client Sending :
Client Sending :   Sending a test message.
Client Sending :
Client Sending :   Later,
Client Sending : Carl
Client Sending : .
Server Response: 250 Ok: queued as 45334
Client Sending : QUIT
Server Response: 221 Bye
```

So my server has now the array of bytes containing the message somewhere in memory.

Question:

> What I should do now with this message ? (assuming the recipient is on
> my machine - no relaying is needed)

Comment: You need a MDA: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent

Comment: When you ask what you should do **now**, it sounds like you mean what to do after the client has send the `QUIT` command. That would actually be too later for anything you wanted to do. After the client has send `.` and before the server sends `250 Ok: queued as 45334`, the server has to store the email. And it must be sure it isn't lost in case of a power failure, so if it was on local disk it has to sync and wait for the disk to confirm that it has been written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the mail to be delivered to the user mailbox, you need a mail delivery agent or MDA.

> A mail delivery agent or message delivery agent (MDA) is a computer
>   software component that is responsible for the delivery of e-mail
>   messages to a local recipient's mailbox. Also called an LDA, or
>   local delivery agent.
>   Within the Internet mail architecture, local message delivery is
>   achieved through a process of handling messages from the message
>   transfer agent, and storing mail into the recipient's environment
>   (typically a mailbox).

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent

Comment: I know I need to deliver this messages via an MDA to the maildir, but at the time of asking my question, I have it only as an array of bytes on my server. What is the communication format between SMTP and MDA ? There must be a standard (some RFC ?) because they are interchangeable.